# Почему progress срабатывает лишь перед получением результата?

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой код:

```
function send(event, php){
console.log("Отправка запроса");
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', php, true);
req.onload = function() {
  if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
    json = JSON.parse(this.response); // Ебанный ie11
        console.log(json);

        // ЗДЕСЬ УКАЗЫВАЕМ ДЕЙСТВИЯ В СЛУЧАЕ УСПЕХА ИЛИ НЕУДАЧИ
        if (json.result == "success") {
            // Если сообщение отправлено
            alert("Сообщение отправлено");
        } else {
            // Если произошла ошибка
            alert("Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено");
        }

} else {alert("Ошибка сервера. Номер: "+req.status);}}; 

req.onerror = function() {alert("Ошибка отправки запроса");};
req.send(new FormData(event.target));
}
```

Мне нужно подкрутить к этой функции прогресс загрузки. Я дописала эти строки:

```
req.onprogress = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Но почему-то этот прогресс срабатывает лишь перед самим получением результата. Сложно объяснить, но грубо говоря:
жмёшь >
ждёшь секунд 5 >
потом за одну секунду в console записывается десяток (в зависимости от размера файла) строк >
и потом сразу срабатывает alert.

Вообще я предполагала, что это должно происходить по мере загрузки, а не в один момент, в виде полного отчёта. Может быть я допустила какую-то ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос XMLHttpRequest состоит из двух фаз:

Стадия отправки (upload). На ней данные загружаются на сервер. Эта фаза может быть долгой для POST-запросов. Для отслеживания прогресса на стадии отправки существует объект типа XMLHttpRequestUpload, доступный как xhr.upload и события на нём.

Стадия скачивания (download). После того, как данные загружены, браузер скачивает ответ с сервера. Если он большой, то это может занять существенное время. На этой стадии используется обработчик xhr.onprogress.

боле подробнее читайте [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-onprogress)

Если вам нужен прогресс на стадии отправки
то используйте

```
xhr.upload.onprogress
```

Comment: спасибо, но почему-то после нажатия "отправить" в консоли сразу появляется одна строчка: loaded: 9044110, total: 9044110. Разве оно не должно плавно увеличиваться и вызываться?

Comment: Я начинала с upload.onprogress, однако он мне выдавал такой же ответ, якобы всё уже загружено, несмотря на то, что я всё равно жду, когда оно загрузится. Нажала > 1 строчка в консоли > жду секунд 10 > alert

Comment: ну это уже браузер. на обработку любого события нужно время. и тут нет фазы обработки запроса сервером.

Comment: так что прогресс сделать плавным не у всех получается. вы думаете почему вешают часики?

Comment: и не могут показать плавно прогресс?

Comment: Не))) Тут не в плавно дело. Тут вообще очень тупая ошибка у меня была. Всё хорошо, всё работает. Я просто пыталась по дурости вычислить прогресс, который идёт в php через js)))

Comment: Ясно. Если вопрос решен можете пометить или закрыть

Comment: благодарю. А можно вас пригласить в этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1153198/Как-подгружать-страницы-без-перезагрузки-на-чистом-js-с-прогрессом ?