# Как подгружать страницы без перезагрузки на чистом js с прогрессом?

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать возможность загружать страницы без перезагрузки и чтобы можно было посмотреть прогресс загрузки этой страницы.
Делаю кнопку:

```
<button onclick="send(event, 'req.html')">Загрузить</button>
```

И вот такую функцию:

```
function send(event, html){
console.log("Отправка запроса");
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', html, true);
req.onload = function() {
  if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
        document.querySelector(".result").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", this.response);
} else {alert("Ошибка сервера. Номер: "+req.status);}}; 

req.onerror = function() {alert("Ошибка отправки запроса");};
req.send();
}
```

Проблема в том, что req.onprogress отрабатывает только на запрос, а не на содержимое документа. Ведь запрос возвращает мне только текст того документа, а в тексте находятся изображения. Грубо говоря страница req.html выглядит так:

```
<img src="big1.png" alt="">
<img src="big2.png" alt="">
<img src="big3.png" alt="">
```

Как можно повесить прогресс на всю страницу из запроса?

Comment: `req.onprogress` и должен отрабатывать только на запрос, потому что этот метод `XMLHttpRequest` запроса. **в теории**, чтобы отследить загрузку всего содержимого `html` (включая Ваши картники из разметки результата ответа), Вам понадобиться обработчик `load`, который нужно вешать на `window`, когда вставите входящую разметку в документ

Comment: @Август ой, а можно пожалуйста по подробнее?

Comment: Ваш `XMLHttpRequest` и его методы отвечают и работают только с покоток `HTTP` запроса. когда запрос завершился, объект `XMLHttpRequest` возвращает результат и удаляется. то, что Вы делаете с результатом запроса - это уже отдельная ветка событий. как вариант решения Вашей проблемы, есть обработчик `load`, который отвечает за окончание загрузки контента (`html` разметка, изображения и т.д). **теоретически**, вы можете повесить его на документ, когда будете вставлять результат Вашего `HTTP` запроса. и после окончания загрузки всех картинок Ваше событие `load` должно сработать.

Comment: @Август попробовала повесить на div "load" или "onload" функцию console.log("загружено") - но это ничего не дало. Не сработала функция. Можете пожалуйста показать пример на каком-нибудь codepen или jsfiddle?

Comment: я тоже проверил, так работать не будет. Вам придется на каждую загруженную картинку вешать событие load. событие load на любых подгруженных изображениях должно работать. то есть, Вы сначала **а)** вешаете на каждое подгруженное изображение событие `load`. **b)** когда все `load` сделают *коллбек* - выполняйте что Вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

Создаёте переменную в JavaScript перед отправкой обнуляете, после получения промежуточного результата изменяет значение на нужное. Вам нужно понять время промежуток перед отправкой запроса и после окончания его.

Comment: не совсем поняла, о чём идёт речь. Я получаю запрос, но я же получаю текст html страницы, а не готовый результат. В тексте есть изображения, но они же в виде <img src="....">. Само же изображение может весить мегабайт 5. Поэтому мне нужно как-то дождаться загрузки всех изображений, получить прогресс и вывести результат .

Comment: Вы думаете они там вместе все одним запросом пройдут?